# Is mov %esi, %esi a no-op or not on x86-64?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, x86-64

I am a bit confused by the comment in one of the header files for the Linux kernel, [arch/x86/include/asm/nops.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/nops.). It states that

> <...> the following instructions are NOT nops in 64-bit mode, for 64-bit mode use K8 or P6 nops instead
>   movl %esi,%esi
>   leal 0x00(%esi),%esi
>   <...>

I guess the author implied the machine instructions ('89 F6' and '8D 76 00', respectively) there rather than assembly instructions. It follows from the description of `LEA` in Intel Software Developer's Manual Vol 2A that the latter instruction (`lea 0x00(%rsi), %esi`) does the same as the the former, `mov %esi,%esi`.

So this reduces to the question, whether `mov %esi,%esi` is actually a no-op on x86-64.

`mov` does not change flags. This kind of `mov` does not change memory either. It seems, if it changes something besides `%rip`, that should be general purpose registers. But I have no clue how it can change the contents of `%rsi` or whatever. If you manipulate the lower half of a general purpose register, the upper half should not change, right?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
mov %esi, %esi
```

zeros out the high 32 bits of %rsi, and is therefore not a no-op on x86_64.

See [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6)

Comment: seeing as your an assembly guy, and this is your 486th answer, does this mean you'll stop answering questions now? (Sorry, lame 486 joke... I remember my 486DX2... and now I'm COMPLETELY off topic)

Comment: Just to add to the answer, the relevant section of the Intel dev manuals is 3.4.1.1 (in Volume 1).

Comment: @Steve: The first platform for which I wrote assembly was the 68k, so I think I have a while to go before I hang it up...

Comment: @Stephen Canon, I see now what happens, thank you. Indeed, it says in the volume 1 of Intel's manual: "32-bit operands generate a 32-bit result, zero-extended to a 64-bit result in the
destination general-purpose register".

Comment: @Michael Foukarakis - thank you for pointing this out. This saves me a lot of time.

Comment: @Michael: Yes, thanks.  I would have pointed out the relevant section myself, but I was at lunch, posting from my phone =)

Answer (score 7):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    void * reg_rsi = 0;

    asm (
        "movq $0x1234567812345678, %%rsi;\n"
        "movl %%esi, %%esi;\n"
        "movq %%rsi, %0;\n"
        : "=r" (reg_rsi)
        : /* no inputs */
        : /* no clobbered */
    );

    printf("reg_rsi = %p\n", reg_rsi);

    return 0;
}
```

This gives "reg_rsi = 0x12345678" for my x86_64 machine.

Comment: You are correct, the same applies to `rax` and `eax`.  HOWEVER: swap the `movl` for an `xor` and it will zero the entire 64 bits.

Comment: Note that **this inline asm is unsafe**: it doesn't declare a clobber on RSI.  The other fix would be to use `"=S"` instead of `"=r"`, to tell the compiler the output register is RSI.  (And omit the last `mov`.)  Or with `"=r"`, use `mov %k0, %k0` to fill in that spot in the template with the name of the 32-bit version of the register it picked.  (Look at the compiler-generated asm, or disassembly as you single-step, to see how it filled in the template.)